# NPM peer dependencies error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, github, npm

Im doing this tutorial on angular js. Im a complete newbie and have never touched it before but would love to learn. I am doing this tutorial here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofASsumsf7E

However im having issues when trying to run the npm install command. This is the error that i am getting.

npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency grunt@~0.4.0 included from grunt-c
ontrib-copy will no

I have no idea how to debug this but its a big roadblock for me. I can try to find other tutorials but I like this one. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

peerDependencies are deprecated in the latest npm versions. This is why you have the warning.

When you use `grunt`you install it locally (which isn't the case in that project from what I can see : https://github.com/colorfest/angularjs/blob/master/package.json).

You may have to run `npm install grunt` at the root of the project.